# Label Encoding do Data Frame no R

Tags: r, dataframe

Tenho uma tabela com 150 colunas de um questionário. E estou tentando fazer um Label Encoding dos dados para fazer análise estatística. Consegui usar o pacote CatEconders para isso que tem a função `LabelEnconder.fit` e `transform`. Porém não consigo aplicar isso em todo o data frame de uma vez.

Tentando com o looping estou obtendo erro ou não consigo dar continuidade

```
for(i in ncol()){
  Dados_cronbach_encoding$i <- LabelEncoder.fit(Dados_cronbach$i)
}
```

Comment: 1) `i in ncol()` está errado, talvez seja `i in 1:ncol(Dados_cronbach)`; 2) Tanto `Dados_cronbach_encoding$i` como `Dados_cronbach$i` devem ser mudados para `Dados_cronbach_encoding[[i]]` e`Dados_cronbach[[i]]`, respetivamente.

Comment: No ponto 2) acima estou a assumir que `Dados_cronbach_encoding` é um data.frame já existente, que não é o `encoding` da coluna número `i` de `Dados_cronbach`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
require( ltm )
require( purrr )

# obras consultadas
#   https://www.statology.org/cronbachs-alpha-in-r/

configuração <- list(
    perguntas    = 15
  , respondentes = 40
)

faz_datos <- function( cfg, sd ){

  # Faz uma tabela em que:
  #  Cada coluna representa uma respondente;
  #  Cada linha representa uma pergunta
 
  # Por cada respondente, escolhe uma resposta típica
  runif( cfg$respondentes, min = 2, max = 8 ) %>%
  
    # Por as perguntas, escolhe respostas pertos de a resposta típica,
    # associadas com a respondente
    map( ~round( rnorm( cfg$perguntas, mean = .x, sd = sd ), 0 ) ) %>%

    unlist %>%
      matrix( nrow = cfg$respondentes, byrow = TRUE ) ->
        datos
      
  colnames( datos ) <- paste0(    'Pergunta', 1:configuração$perguntas )
  rownames( datos ) <- paste0( 'respondente', 1:configuração$respondentes )

  datos[ datos <  1 ] <- 1
  datos[ datos > 10 ] <- 10
  
  datos
}

# ------------------------------------------------------------
# Respostas com alta consistência interna
# ------------------------------------------------------------

alta  <- faz_datos( cfg = configuração, sd = 0.8 )

alta[ 1:4,1:4]
#             Pergunta1 Pergunta2 Pergunta3 Pergunta4
#respondente1         2         3         2         1
#respondente2         6         5         5         6
#respondente3         4         5         5         4
#respondente4         7         4         4         6

# ------------------------------------------------------------
# Respostas com baixa consistência interna
# ------------------------------------------------------------

baixa <- faz_datos( cfg = configuração, sd = 5.0 )

baixa[ 1:4,1:4]
#             Pergunta1 Pergunta2 Pergunta3 Pergunta4
#respondente1         1         1         3         1
#respondente2         3         3         1        10
#respondente3         1        10         4         7
#respondente4        10         7         4        10

# ----------------------
cronbach.alpha( alta )
# ----------------------
#
#Cronbach's alpha for the 'alta' data-set
#
#Items: 15
#Sample units: 40
#alpha: 0.982

# ----------------------
cronbach.alpha( baixa )
# ----------------------
#
#Cronbach's alpha for the 'baixa' data-set
#
#Items: 15
#Sample units: 40
#alpha: 0.671

# ------------------------------------------------------------
z <- lapply(
    seq( 1.0, 4.0, by=0.5 )
  , function( sd ) faz_datos( cfg = configuração, sd = sd )
)

str( z )
#List of 7
# $ : num [1:40, 1:15] 8 3 5 3 4 7 7 4 7 5 ...
#  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  .. ..$ : chr [1:40] "respondente1" "respondente2" "respondente3" "respondente4" ...
#  .. ..$ : chr [1:15] "Pergunta1" "Pergunta2" "Pergunta3" "Pergunta4" #...
# $ : num [1:40, 1:15] 10 3 5 2 5 3 5 3 3 6 ...
#  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  .. ..$ : chr [1:40] "respondente1" "respondente2" "respondente3" "respondente4" ...
#  .. ..$ : chr [1:15] "Pergunta1" "Pergunta2" "Pergunta3" "Pergunta4" #...
# ...

sapply( z, function( a ) cronbach.alpha( a )$alpha )
#[1] 0.9795 0.9506 0.9281 0.8327 0.8698 0.6683 0.7548
```